# How do I associate a firebase sub-entry to a main entry? (explanation in comments)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The JSON:

```
{
  "coffee-shops" : {
    "-KJ4I4D-Jrqrzc9wP42C" : {
      "coffeeShopName" : "Starbucks",
      "coffeeShopRating" : 3.5,
    "-KJ4VVB51wx9NpEKtjxQ" : {
      "coffeeShopName" : "Starbucks",
      "coffeeShopRating" : 1,
      "coffeeShopReview" : "R",
      "coffeeShopReviewerName" : "Charles"
    },
    "-KJEJ6MpQwOHcay_9k6v" : {
      "coffeeShopName" : "Starbucks",
      "coffeeShopRating" : 4,
      "coffeeShopReview" : "B",
      "coffeeShopReviewerName" : "Charles"
    }
  }
  },
  "users" : {
    "02a54e06-9635-4e22-9bb7-c0ddcd9c6f4f" : {
      "email" : "charles@gmail.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "thecoffeeguy"
    },
    "03fe2c17-3c66-442c-a63d-4a1e02fd660c" : {
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "Charles"
    },
    "16a7279f-5478-4f3f-b5f8-2f261d166d92" : {
      "email" : "tester@gmail.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "haha"
    },
    "23275f65-8e16-4ede-9236-21485b7493b9" : {
      "email" : "boo@gmail.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "boo"
    },
    "a5ed6962-76bc-476a-b432-6787e45badfc" : {
      "email" : "mesbekmek@gmail.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "mesbekmek"
    }
  }
}
```

Some context: I'm making a coffee app and I need to have the reviews be specific to the coffee shop a user is at. Right now, all reviews that have ever been made will show up on my tableview.

This isn't so much a "how to code" question, but me wondering how to approach this and how I might solve it.

This is what I think I should do:

1. get a specific coffee shop's uuid
2. iterate over the reviews because they are sub-entries in my coffee shop model
3. get data from iterating over the reviews, then see if the uuid of the cell(?) selected matches the review uuid

This doesn't really sound right to me, so any help would be great.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Went ahead and made those changes. I had to shorten it because I have a lot of test accounts and reviews I made.

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit. Let's clean up the comments...

Comment: Is there anyway for me to see what other people have edited on my post?

I put those comments there because it wouldn't let me submit my edit, but I guess it's no longer needed.

Comment: You can see the complete history by clicking on the [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37582181/revisions) link. I removed the comments, because they seemed not needed (and I might have enough rep to be allowed to post it).

Comment: Great! I'll take a look at Gabriele's post. It seems like it's exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your db in a different way.

```
coffee-shops:
|--coffeeId1
|--coffeeId2
|--coffeeId3

reviews:
|--coffeeId1
|----reviewId1
|----reviewId2
|--coffeeId2
|----reviewIdX
|----reviewIdXx
```

When you insert a review you can use the same key of the coffee-shop.
In this way all the reviews of the same coffee shop is under the same ref.

You can achieve it using something like this:

```
ref(reviews).child(coffeeshop.getKey()).push();
```

Comment: Great answer! [Avoiding nested data is a best practice when you're using the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele! I'm still not sure how I would need to structure my data, and after that, not sure where I would need to do what you are saying in your answer. Should it be done in my `Reviews` or CoffeeShops` class?

Or should I do this in my `submitReviewButtonTapped`? I don't really have any code to show as I've just been trying it in my project and am not sure how to proceed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlesKang When the user submits the review, you add the value in the reviews ref taking the key from the coffee shop to obtain a new ref (reviews/coffeeId). Use this new ref to push and add the new review.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, should my `coffee-shops` entry only have the name of the coffee shop? Or is the data I currently have okay?


Instead of figuring out how to submit the review, should I look to see if there's a method that lets me query the coffee-shops or reviews and get the key.

Comment: @CharlesKang It depends by your whole project and final purpose and it is only a personal opinion. I would put only the name (or other properties of the coffee-shop, not the reviews data)